# setting selectedColor in a colorpikcer

Tags: apache-flex, color-picker

How do you set the selectedColor of a colorpicker when you bind data from a database?

I have a bindable variable, objProject, with a field called color and it has a color code such as #ff00ff in it. I want to set the selectedColor. I tried to cast the color as a uint, but no joy.

```
objProject = cmbProject.selectedItem;
c = uint(objProject.color);

<mx:ColorPicker id="graphColor"  x="17" y="219" width="128" height="40"
    selectedColor="{c}" editable="true"  />
```

I did try selectedColor="{objProject.color}" and that didn't work either.

Suggestions?

Comment: What is the value and/or data type of objProject.color?

Comment: Also; what is the implementation for the 'c' variable.  Is it Bindable?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you can't do this:

```
objProject = cmbProject.selectedItem;
graphColor.selectedColor = uint(objProject.color);
```

Is there a specific reason you need to use binding in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I see - you have a hex value -

Try this :

```
Number('0x' + yourColorString.replace('#','') );
```

The 0x notation specifies a hex radix, thus when it is evaluated it will convert the hex value into a numerical one.  Yes, you could replace the `#` with the `0x` instead, but doing it this works even if they did not include the hash.

Going the other way is easy as well (from number back to hex):

```
String( '#' + yourNumericValue.toString(16) );
```